# Highcharts click in bar to zoom

Tags: javascript, html, api, highcharts

Working with highcharts API I have a bar chart in which I would like that when I click on any of them, a zoom is made to centre the visualisation on that bar.

[image]

I can do it by clicking and dragging but I would like to add an event to the graph so that it zooms automatically when I click on any of the bars.

Answer (score 0):

To simulate zooming in the select plot chart area after clicking on the point use [point.events.click](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.bar.point.events.click) and then set [Axis#setExtremes](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#setExtremes) for each axis.

```
let chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
  series: [{
    type: 'bar',
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
    pointStart: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1),
    pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
    point: {
      events: {
        click: function() {
          let xAxis = chart.xAxis[0],
            yAxis = chart.yAxis[0];
          xAxis.setExtremes(Date.UTC(2010, 0, 2), Date.UTC(2010, 0, 6));
          yAxis.setExtremes(50, 100);
        }
      }
    }
  }],
  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime'
  },

});

document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
  chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1), Date.UTC(2010, 0, 12));
  chart.yAxis[0].setExtremes(20, 200);
})
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/sjr3gu9c/